# angular - strictTemplates true ignores type guards

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I have got error

> Property 'pricePerItem' does not exist on type 'ShipProductDetail'.

(the type of product is ProductDetail | ShipProductDetail)

but I've used sort of Type Guards

```
    <span
        *ngIf="product.hasOwnProperty('pricePerItem')"
        class="text-uppercase smaller"
      >
        {{ product.pricePerItem.priceWithVat | i18nNumber | ogCurrency }}
    </span>
```

Is it a bug or not?

### UPDATE

It's not a bug its my fault :)

I worked it out with

```
hasPricePerItem(
    product: ProductDetail | ShipProductDetail
  ): PriceAndVatModel | null {
    if ((product as ProductDetail).pricePerItem) {
      return (product as ProductDetail).pricePerItem;
    }
    return null;
  }

<span *ngIf="hasPricePerItem(product)" class="text-uppercase smaller">
        {{ hasPricePerItem(product)?.priceWithVat | i18nNumber | ogCurrency }}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, typeguard does not work with `ngIf`. And `hasOwnProperty` is not a type-guard